# Showing that $i \notin \mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{4}}i)$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am trying to show that $i \notin \mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{4}}i)$. Here is my attempt:

The minimal polynomial of $5^{\frac{1}{4}}i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^4-5$. Considering the evaluation homomorphism $\text{ev}_{\alpha}$ of $\alpha = 5^{\frac{1}{4}}i$ from $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ to $\mathbb{C}$, we can deduce that

$$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^4-5)} \cong \text{Im } \text{ev}_{\alpha} = \mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{4}}i)$$.

We thus know that $\mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{4}}i) = \{k_n\alpha^n+k_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots+k_1\alpha^1+k_0\vert n\in\mathbb{N}, k_i\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. However, from here onwards I struggled to show that $i$ cannot be expressed as a polynomial in $\alpha$.

My second attempt was to show that $\mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{4}}i)=\{a+b\alpha \vert a,b \in\mathbb{Q}\}$ and from this deduce that $i$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{4}}i)$. However, again, I struggled to show the set equality, and even if I assumed the equality it still wasn't clear how to show that we can't express $i$ as $a+b\alpha$ for $a,b \neq 0$.

So I'm wondering if my approaches are correct or whether there are simpler/alternative ways to tackle this. Thanks.

Comment: If you already know that the elements of $\Bbb{Q}(5^{1/4}i)$ have the form $k_0+k_1\alpha+k_2\alpha^2+k_3\alpha^3$ why are you bothering with the second attempt that is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Anyway, the best approach to this question depends on how much field theory you have covered. For example, have you done Galois theory? If not, then you may need to show that the square of a generic element  cannot be $-1$. In other words, there are no solutions to
$$(k_0+k_1\alpha+k_2\alpha^2+k_3\alpha^3)^2=-1$$ with $k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3$ rational. To that end remember that the representation of an element as a linear rational combination of $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3$ is unique.

Comment: If $i$ were in that field so would be $5^{1/4}$ and then $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} (5^{1/4})\subseteq \mathbb{Q} (5^{1/4}i)$. This would be a problem as both these fields will be equal. All this assumes that the fields under consideration are subfields of the field of complex numbers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: if we ignore complex numbers, then we can only say that $K=\mathbb {Q} [x] /(x^4-5)$ has only two roots of the polynomial $x^4-5$. If there were an element $\alpha\in K$ with $\alpha^2=-1$ then we would have all the four roots of the polynomial in $K$ namely $\beta, - \beta, \alpha\beta, - \alpha\beta$ where $\beta =[x] \in K$. But this would mean that $K$ is splitting field. Is there any way via Galois theory to show that this $K$ can't be splitting field?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I suspect that the approach in your comment is the only way out here, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah I haven't covered that much Galois theory. I know the Galois correspondence theorem and how to use it to identify Galois group, but not much more than that. Would it be possible to follow that approach without going beyond how much Galois theory that I know?

Comment: Yeah, I'm apparently at my dullest.  @ParamanandSingh's approach is simpler. The field $L=\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of5,i)$ is a splitting field of $x^4-5$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. If $i$ were an element of $K=\Bbb{Q}(i\root4\of5)$, then $K$ would be a splitting field. But $K$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of5)$ which cannot be a splitting field because it is real. Done.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Yes that's it. Thanks!